# I want to sorting step by in c# in gui

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have wrote this code for c#

```
void SelectionSort()
    {
        clearFontColor();
        int i, j, min, temp;
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (input[min] > input[j])
                {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            if (min != i)
            {
                temp = input[i];
                input[i] = input[min];
                input[min] = temp;
            }

        }
         show(input);
    }
```

But this is doing only one step and later it stops.How to achieve that.

The button for sort action is like

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // lbl_step.Visible = true;
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            InsertionSort();
        }
        else if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            bubble();
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            SelectionSort();
        }

    }
```

and its working for just one time after that it stops working.

Comment: This is not C. You don't have to declare all your variables at the start of the method.

Comment: If I am reading all your code correctly, the array you pass is by reference. Therefore when you sort the first time the array is sorted. Then the second time the array is already sorted. Am I missing something? Is this the question you are asking?

Comment: ya so i wanted to ask that how can i do it by step by step

Comment: So the question is how to show one step of the sort at a time?

Comment: Then move `show(input);` into your for loop

Comment: ya how to do it one step at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is correct you have do something like this. So your code will run through and show the change howevever, this is happening so faster you won't see it on the GUI. You need to make variables i a class member. Then in your button click, you increment i.

So the summary: Set i to a number each button click. Then your method will only do one iteration and show the user interface. To continue you click the button again and increment i (make sure to check bounds).

```
int i;
void SelectionSort()
{
    clearFontColor();
    int j, temp;
    min = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (input[min] > input[j])
        {
            min = j;
        }
    }
    if (min != i)
    {
        temp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[min];
        input[min] = temp;
    }
    show(input);
}
```